# Minimum range when importing descriptors?

Tags: output-script-descriptors

When importing descriptors with a range less than 1000, it seems to be ignored. Is this deliberate? I could‘t find anything about this in the [docs](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/importdescriptors.html).

To reproduce, first, create an empty wallet:

`bitcoin-cli -regtest -named createwallet wallet_name=test disable_private_keys=true blank=true descriptors=true`

Import a descriptor with range 10:

`bitcoin-cli -regtest -named importdescriptors requests='[{ "desc":  "'"wpkh([9a6a2580/84'/1'/179']tpubDCMRAYcH71Gib1rASZpnMPpJbj7S1Nzmao1nPv5Jrb8pwSUimsH5TmK842UhnGPJbiNThzxhK4BpRUCsjSckpNYkH9kjKGWLd94yhZFN94J/0/*)#rljv8npg"'", "timestamp":"now", "active": true, "range":10}]'`

Check the range with `listdescriptors`:

```
{
  "wallet_name": "test",
  "descriptors": [
    {
      "desc": "wpkh([9a6a2580/84'/1'/179']tpubDCMRAYcH71Gib1rASZpnMPpJbj7S1Nzmao1nPv5Jrb8pwSUimsH5TmK842UhnGPJbiNThzxhK4BpRUCsjSckpNYkH9kjKGWLd94yhZFN94J/0/*)#rljv8npg",
      "timestamp": 1666876980,
      "active": true,
      "internal": false,
      "range": [
        0,
        999
      ],
      "next": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

In contrast, if I import a descriptor with a range larger than 1000, it seems to be respected:

`bitcoin-cli -regtest -named importdescriptors requests='[{ "desc":  "'"wpkh([9a6a2580/84'/1'/180']tpubDCMRAYcH71GibuLuWcDkwmmY1gXkXhf162QuEHxkMpZPSi7xck2eGQ6MRGKxNTeY8P1FiFTPCLA5x7qZpFx84fnnrNQFpSnUCwd1nPG8Mk9/0/*)#u49n3vuy"'", "timestamp":"now", "active": true, "range":2000}]'`

Check the range again with `listdescriptors`:

```
(…)
{
      "desc": "wpkh([9a6a2580/84'/1'/180']tpubDCMRAYcH71GibuLuWcDkwmmY1gXkXhf162QuEHxkMpZPSi7xck2eGQ6MRGKxNTeY8P1FiFTPCLA5x7qZpFx84fnnrNQFpSnUCwd1nPG8Mk9/0/*)#u49n3vuy",
      "timestamp": 1666876980,
      "active": true,
      "internal": false,
      "range": [
        0,
        2000
      ],
      "next": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time we call the `DescriptorScriptPubKeyMan::TopUp` method (which happens quite a lot internally, including whenever we add a new descriptor) [it automatically adjusts](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/1bad29fe02096b269858b192a4a91c785a44e505/src/wallet/scriptpubkeyman.cpp#L2130) the range-end to be at least as big as (next index + keypool size).

If you launch bitcoind with specifying a `keypool` smaller than the range you want to use (e.g. `bitcoind -regtest -keypool=5`), you will observe the behaviour you expected.

*(Thank you for providing the steps to reproduce.)*

Comment: Thanks!

1. Do you think the importdescriptors documentation should be improved? Your answer was not obvious to me. I wouldn't mind creating a PR clarifying this.

2. Is the key pool size related to address lookahead? I.e. with a range of `[0, 999]`, will Bitcoin Core detect incoming transactions on the 1000 first addresses of that output descriptor? If so, does importing _a lot_ of brand new descriptors warrant a smaller range to save on memory/processing, in cases where we’re in full control of the addresses shared from the various descriptors?

Comment: You're definitely welcome to open a PR or issue! I think clarifying the connection between keypool is appropriate. It's probably not super crucial because a larger range should never lead to unexpected/dangerous behaviour, but yeah I suppose (but am not sure) that when importing large amounts of descriptors this can lead to performance impact. Even if it would have just saved you a bunch of time figuring this out, it's probably worth adding to the docs imo!